# Min() returns higher values than max()

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I'm using this query in SQLite

```
SELECT
  x.Level,
  x.Parent,
  x.Ranking,
  y.minr,
  y.maxr
FROM
  GroupRanking AS x
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    Level,
    Parent,
    min(Ranking) AS minr,
    max(Ranking) AS maxr
  FROM
    GroupRanking
  GROUP BY
    Level, Parent
) AS y
ON
  x.Level = y.Level AND x.Parent = y.Parent
ORDER BY
  x.Level, x.Parent, x.Ranking
LIMIT 16;
```

Observed result

```
   Level Parent     Ranking        minr        maxr
1      1      1 -1691668126 -1691668126  -763167442
2      1      1  1805402547 -1691668126  -763167442
3      1      1   331841336 -1691668126  -763167442
4      1      1  -763167442 -1691668126  -763167442
5      1      2 -1649664922 -1649664922 -1698226108
6      1      2  1050628156 -1649664922 -1698226108
7      1      2  1195643104 -1649664922 -1698226108
8      1      2 -1698226108 -1649664922 -1698226108
9      1      3   742489555   742489555 -1068497810
10     1      3   613872842   742489555 -1068497810
11     1      3   267740911   742489555 -1068497810
12     1      3 -1068497810   742489555 -1068497810
13     1      4  1053184739  1053184739  -437919960
14     1      4  -843952369  1053184739  -437919960
15     1      4  -769107202  1053184739  -437919960
16     1      4  -437919960  1053184739  -437919960
```

The results from `min()` and `max()` are wrong and the order of the observations as well. The problem seems to be with the order.

Here is an example of `GroupRanking`

```
CREATE TABLE Base (BaseValue);
INSERT INTO Base (BaseValue) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Base (BaseValue) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO Base (BaseValue) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO Base (BaseValue) VALUES (4);

CREATE TABLE GroupRanking AS 
SELECT
  x1.BaseValue AS Level,
  x2.BaseValue AS Parent,
  x3.BaseValue AS Child,
  random() AS Ranking
FROM
  Base AS x1
CROSS JOIN
  Base AS x2
CROSS JOIN
  Base AS x3;
```

Comment: This doesnt make sense. Can you prepare a http://sqlfiddle.com/ to reproduce this error?

Comment: Is Ranking a stored value (in a table), or is it calculated on the fly (like in a view)? In the latter case, this could explain that you get funny results. The query plan will revisit the same values more than once without expecting they change at every visit.

Comment: Would you show the schema for GroupRanking?

Comment: What is the data type of the column `Ranking`?

Comment: I've added a reproducible example. All columns are integer. Ranking is stored in a table.

Comment: Well, it can not be reproduced. The result [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/26323/1/0) looks good to me.